# Dividing two doubles gives wrong result in Xcode console

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I was trying some things in Xcode, and ran into an unexplained situation where Xcode gives me a wrong result for a simple division:

```
let a : Double = 0.235
let b : Double = 0.001
let nrOfDivisions = a / b

print("Divisions: ", nrOfDivisions) //prints 234.99999999999997
```

Strange enough, if I divide from `0.230 ... 0.234` to the same amount of `0.001`, I get correct results, but starting from `0.235 ... 0.239` I get these wrong results.
I've tested now with `0.225, 0.226, 0.227, 0.245, 0.246, 0.247` and they all divide correctly.

What might be the issue here? It is a bug in Xcode, or am I missing something?

Comment: What is wrong about the result, this is quite normal for floating point types?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is probably due to this issue: [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency/3730040#3730040). Were you thinking that Apple implemented floating point wrong? In the Java World, these questions came up quite often, and `BigDecimal` was the solution, you can read about that.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I read somewhere that this happens with Floats, and not with Doubles, because Floats have 7 precision decimals, while the Doubles have 15 precision decimals. Thus, making Floats less precise. Also, in my observation it doesn't occur with the other numbers I tested, only with that small range I described, although my experiment didn't include lots of trials.

Comment: @Starsky This happens under one circumstance or another, with *every* fixed-precision data type, whether `Float` (32 bits), `Double` (64 bits), `Float80` (80 bits) and beyond. It's no different than asking the computer to: "Give me an exact representation of 1/3 in decimal, using only `n` digits". For any `n < ∞`, the answer will necessarily and inescapably be imprecise. E.g. if you only had 2 digits to work with, the closest approximation is `0.33`. But you're off the mark by `0.003333333...`